# seo frienly url in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

present link  http://www.easydownlink.com/profile.php?uid=105

i like to show this is as  http://www.easydownlink.com/johny12  please give code for it

dudes this is my complete code in htaccess file. i confused where to add mod rewrite for friendly urls.  please help me.   please give ur valuble suggestions.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Options -Indexes

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # 1 YEAR
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    # 1 WEEK
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    # 2 DAYS
    <FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=172800, proxy-revalidate"
    </FilesMatch>
    # 1 MIN
    #<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|php)$">
    #Header set Cache-Control "max-age=60, private, proxy-revalidate"
    #</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 3 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 days"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 3 days"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 3 days"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: `i confused where to add mod rewrite` You can put them at the end of the file, it almost doesn't matter. Also to do what you want I would re-architect the URL profile parameter to accept the username  because how are you going to match it? It should be something like `profile.php?u=johny12` (which should be unique) then locate that in the DB and select the page by UID. Then you can make friendly URL's. That's what I would do.

Comment: How do you expect to summon "johny12" from "105"?